# Is it possible to remove a single file from a Time Capsule backup?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, time-machine, time-capsule

I have a Time Capsule and it has backup images of my computer.

There is a file within the backup that I wish to delete but I do not want to delete the entire backup.

Is this possible?

Comment: How do I mark off both answers as the correct one?  I'd even use time as teh tie breaker but they were submitted at the same time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you wnat to delete all backups of a single file, but not the whole backup (all backups of all files). correct?

Just fire up Time Machine, right-click on the file you want to erase from your backup and select `Delete all backups of <filename>`

Answer (score 4):

While navigating Time Machine, go to the present view, and click the little gear icon in the toolbar of the Finder while you have the file you want to delete selected. Simply click the option to Delete all Time Machine backups of this file, and the file will be gone forever.

[Courtesy of PeggyD](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=5301924&postcount=3)